# Kivy: Using Toolbar together with ScreenManager. What I'm doing wrong here?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

So I have a Toolbar that work perfectly well on a single screen, but I need two screens. One main screen and one setup screen. This should be easy done with ScreenManager, I hoped.

**When I run this code I get the following error: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**' What I'm doing wrong?**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.metrics import dp

kv = """
ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
    SetupScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'    

    MDToolbar:
        id: tool1
        title:'My Demo App'
        pos_hint:{'top':1}
        right_action_items : [["dots-vertical", lambda x: app.menu.open()]]

<SetupScreen>:
    name: 'setup'            
"""


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SetupScreen(Screen):
    pass


# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))
sm.add_widget(SetupScreen(name='setup'))


class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        menu_items = [
            {
                "text": f"Option {opt}",
                "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                "height": dp(40),
                "on_release": lambda x=f"Option {opt}": self.menu_callback(x),
            } for opt in range(4)
        ]

        menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=sm.ids.tool1,
            items=menu_items,
            width_mult=3
        )
        return screen


    def menu_callback(self, text_item):
        print(text_item)


DemoApp().run()
```

Comment: What is the `root` widget, is it defined in `test.kv` ? If so, please post it, otherwise you might have to change it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep seeing this same error in many posts. When your `build()` method returns the result from `Builder.load_file()` or `Builder.load_string()`, then your root widget (and your entire GUI) is defined in the `kv`. So the lines:

```
# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))
sm.add_widget(SetupScreen(name='setup'))
```

are creating another instance of your GUI, but that instance is not used, and any references to that `sm` will have no effect on the `ScreenManager` that is actually in your GUI (the one built via the `kv`). So, you can start by eliminating those lines completely.

Then, to fix the actual problem you need to change your construction of the `MDDropdownMenu` to something like:

```
    self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
        # caller=sm.ids.tool1,
        caller=screen.get_screen('main').ids.tool1,
        items=menu_items,
        width_mult=3
    )
```

using `self.menu` instead of just `menu` saves a reference to the `menu`. Otherwise, the `menu` is created, then discarded. Since `sm` is not part of your GUI, you must use a reference to your actual GUI. The line:

```
    caller=screen.get_screen('main').ids.tool1,
```

uses the `ScreenMananger` (`screen`) that is returned by the `Builder`. Then using `get_screen()`, it gets the `main` `Screen` (since that is the one that contains the `tool1` `id`). And finally uses that `id` to get a reference to the `MDToolbar`.

Comment: Thank you so much, for brining me back on track again. The clue her for me was the missing method 'get_screen()'